# Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <form> cannot appear as a descendant of <form>. How to solve this console warning?

Tags: reactjs, forms, nested, console, warnings

```
const PaymentDetailsTabs = () => {
    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
    return (
        <>
            <div className="Payment-details-tab">
                <div>
                    <p>There are no any payment methods yet</p>
                    <RedButton onClick={() => setModalShow(true)} title="Add Method" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <AddPaymentPopup
                        show={modalShow}
                        onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
                    />
                </div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
 }
```

Comment: While asking question please try to explain how and where you are facing problem along with error log and your code.

Comment: we cannot see form elements in the code you have attached. can you check inside AddPaymentPopup whether there is a code-like `form` element inside another `form` element? That's what the warning is about.